# What equipment is needed to perform simple plant electrophysiology?

Tags: plant-physiology, electrophysiology

What is the minimum needed equipment to perform simple plant electrophysiology? I am looking for some simple experiments that I could run at home for learning. Ideally, I would transfer the skills to stud neuroscience later on (the skills could be related to operating a microscope, doing recordings with microelectrodes, signal processing, statistics, etc). How expensive this would be?

Comment: I think it will be difficult to do at home. You would need to dissolve the cell wall first, to do electrophysiology. You would need cellulase+pectinase.

Comment: @WYSIWYG dissolve the cell wall? I don't know about plants, but the popular methods in neuroscience, such as patch clamp, measure the voltage between the plasma and the environment. The membrane has to stay intact so you can measure the current which depolarises (and sometimes hyperpolarises) the cell.

Comment: @rumtscho In neuroscience methods the clamp is fixed on the membrane. In this case there is an additional layer of cell wall that is quite permeable. IMO you won't be able to attach the clamp on the membrane properly.

Answer (score 1):

Electrophysiology on plant cells means single-cell recordings, as there are no gross compound action potentials.  As you correctly say, this means **micro-electrodes**; this in turn means **computerized manipulation of the pipettes**, a decent **microscope**, **signal amplifier**, **recording software**, **stimulator slash voltage/current control**, **Faraday cage**, **analysis software** (Matlab), and not unimportantly a **vibration-free workbench** (whole departments have moved house due to micrometer vibrations in the building). I guess you should think anywhere between 10k - 100k (dollars, euros whatever) as a reasonable estimate.

A student internship would be advisable finance-wise, but especially because single cell recordings, and electrophysiological skills in general, are relatively difficult to master.